# Enable MethodSecurityInterceptor to publish AuthorizedEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to audit successful authorisations in a spring-boot 2.X application.
So I tried to start listening for `AuthorizedEvent` but that event isn't published until `AbstractSecurityInterceptor.publishAuthorizationSuccess` is set to true.

This application mostly uses `@Secured` and `@PreAuthorize`/`@PostAuthorize` annotations so the interceptor I'm trying to listen to is `MethodSecurityInterceptor` (It also gives me security roles being authorized against that `FilterSecurityInterceptor` does not)

I don't see any way to configure `MethodSecurityInterceptor` and enable event publishing other than through `BeanPostProcessor` which feels fragile.

Is there a better way to enable `MethodSecurityInterceptor.publishAuthorizationSuccess` than through `BeanPostProcessor`?

Comment: Manually configure the `MethodSecurityINterceptor` which is probably even more fragile.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah, that's another option but, as you pointed out, it feels even more fragile.
Overall it just feels like it's worth contributing to the spring-security project to expose this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9705) in the spring-security github repo.

According to the [reply](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9705#issuecomment-832051265) there is no better way to configure `MethodSecurityInterceptor` right now and they are making [major changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/9630) in that part of the code so no point in improving anything right now.

So best way to configure `MethodSecurityInterceptor` is through a `BeanPostProcessor` like below:

```
@Component
public class MethodSecurityInterceptorPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof MethodSecurityInterceptor) {
            ((MethodSecurityInterceptor) bean).setPublishAuthorizationSuccess(true);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```